# Setting Azure protection's sensitivity label with vba

Tags: excel, vba, azure

This pop-up message appears while creating a new workbook in Excel using a vba macro, which has to be manually set and it stops the code temporarily.
[image]

I have seen some potential solutions like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/office.labelinfo)

```
  Sub SetLabelInfo()
  Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo
  Set myLabelInfo = Application.ActiveDocument.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
  With myLabelInfo
  .ActionId = "5cc46055-305d-4bc1-8f5f-5edf82231378"
  .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED
  .ContentBits = 4
  .IsEnabled = True
  .Justification = "Some justification needed only if downgrading label."
  .LabelId = "9203368f-916c-4d59-8292-9f1c6a1e8f39"
  .LabelName = "MyLabelName"
  .SetDate = Now()
  .SiteId = "6c15903a-880e-4e17-818a-6cb4f7935615"
 End With
End Sub
```

but I can't even access the Object `office.labelInfo` or `sensitevitylabel` is there any reference, which I should enable first?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).